# Unable to include html file in other via ng-include with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to include a file **ProdDetailCarousel.html** in another file, **prodDetail.html**, via ng-include. The contents are loaded but the script of the page doesnt work. Can someone help?

**prodDetail.html**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p >Box 1 <ng-include src="'ProdDetailCarousel.html'"></ng-include></p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p>Box 3</p></div>
    </div>
```

**ProdDetailCarousel.html**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
    <script src="../../bower_components/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="title">
    <span>bliss arts</span>
</div>
<div id="sync1" style="width:300px; height:300px" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/2.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/3.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/4.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>

</div>
<div id="sync2" style="height:300px;width:300px " class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" width="60" height="51"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/2.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/3.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/4.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>

</div>

<script>


   $(document).ready(function() {

       var sync1 = $("#sync1");
       var sync2 = $("#sync2");

       sync1.owlCarousel({
           singleItem : true,
           slideSpeed : 50,
           navigation: true,
           pagination:false,
           lazyLoad : true,
           afterAction : syncPosition,
           responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
       });

       sync2.owlCarousel({
           items : 5,
           itemsDesktop      : [1199,5],
           itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,5],
           itemsTablet       : [768,5],
           itemsMobile       : [479,5],
           pagination:false,
           responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
           afterInit : function(el){
               el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
           }
       });

       function syncPosition(el){
           var current = this.currentItem;
           $("#sync2")
                   .find(".owl-item")
                   .removeClass("synced")
                   .eq(current)
                   .addClass("synced")
           if($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
               center(current)
           }
       }

       $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
           sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
       });

       function center(number){
           var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
           var num = number;
           var found = false;
           for(var i in sync2visible){
               if(num === sync2visible[i]){
                   var found = true;
               }
           }

           if(found===false){
               if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                   sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
               }else{
                   if(num - 1 === -1){
                       num = 0;
                   }
                   sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
               }
           } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
               sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
           } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
               sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
           }

       }

   });

</script>

</body>
```

I am able to see the images, but unable to implement the CAROUSEL implemented in the javascript. Please note that individually **ProdDetailCarousel.html** works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-include` doesn't execute the stuff that's in your script tag. You could place a directive around it and use the `postLink` method to connect your `owlCarousel` to the directives element. Also the css `link` tags and the `script` tag on the top of your template won't work. You'd have to add these outside angular in your container view, where you also load the angular script. Also don't forget to change `myApp` for the name of your app in my example. For more info on directives I would recommend this guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.

This would be your directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('carousel', function() {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'ProdDetailCarousel.html',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var sync1 = element.find("#sync1");
           var sync2 = element.find("#sync2");

           sync1.owlCarousel({
               singleItem : true,
               slideSpeed : 50,
               navigation: true,
               pagination:false,
               lazyLoad : true,
               afterAction : syncPosition,
               responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
           });

           sync2.owlCarousel({
               items : 5,
               itemsDesktop      : [1199,5],
               itemsDesktopSmall     : [979,5],
               itemsTablet       : [768,5],
               itemsMobile       : [479,5],
               pagination:false,
               responsiveRefreshRate : 100,
               afterInit : function(el){
                   el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
               }
           });

           function syncPosition(el){
               var current = this.currentItem;
               $("#sync2")
                       .find(".owl-item")
                       .removeClass("synced")
                       .eq(current)
                       .addClass("synced")
               if($("#sync2").data("owlCarousel") !== undefined){
                   center(current)
               }
           }

           $("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var number = $(this).data("owlItem");
               sync1.trigger("owl.goTo",number);
           });

           function center(number){
               var sync2visible = sync2.data("owlCarousel").owl.visibleItems;
               var num = number;
               var found = false;
               for(var i in sync2visible){
                   if(num === sync2visible[i]){
                       var found = true;
                   }
               }

               if(found===false){
                   if(num>sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                       sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num - sync2visible.length+2)
                   }else{
                       if(num - 1 === -1){
                           num = 0;
                       }
                       sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num);
                   }
               } else if(num === sync2visible[sync2visible.length-1]){
                   sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", sync2visible[1])
               } else if(num === sync2visible[0]){
                   sync2.trigger("owl.goTo", num-1)
               }

           }
        }
    };

});
```

This would be your **prodDetail.html** template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p >Box 1 <carousel></carousel></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p>Box 2</p></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 "><p>Box 3</p></div>
</div>
```

This would be your **ProdDetailCarousel.html** template:

```
<div class="title">
    <span>bliss arts</span>
</div>
<div id="sync1" style="width:300px; height:300px" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/2.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/3.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/4.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>

</div>
<div id="sync2" style="height:300px;width:300px " class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" width="60" height="51"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/2.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/3.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="img/4.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>
    <div  class="item"><img src="img/bg.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Pepijn .
But I still face an issue while loading it. It throws the error **bold sync1.owlCarousel is not a function**bold.
I think its not loading the carousel js which are linked in the prodDetail.html

Comment: oops I got it. The sequence of <link> tag was wrong. Thanks @Pepijn :D